# Service Value Isn't Persistent Between Parent Component and Children Component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services

I am trying to set a value in a service from one component and read it another.

The hierarchy of my components is as: parent => child => grandchild

If I set the service value in the first child component the parent gets the correct value from the service whereas if I set the value in the child more inner child the parent component doesn't get the correct value.

Below is code:

service.ts

```
 @Injectable()
    export class ConfirmationDialogService {
        componentHasDirtyForm: boolean;// value to set
        constructor(private confirmationDialogReferenceService: ConfirmationDialogReferenceService,
                    private dialog: MatDialog) { }
```

parentComponent.ts

```
constructor(private confirmService: ConfirmationDialogService) {
}

ngOnInit() {
}

isDirty(): boolean {
    console.log(this.confirmService.componentHasDirtyForm)
    return this.confirmService.componentHasDirtyForm;
}
```

ChildComponent.ts

```
constructor(private confirmService: ConfirmationDialogService) { }

ngAfterViewChecked(){
    this.confirmService.componentHasDirtyForm = this.generalInfoForm.dirty;
}
```

GrandchildComponent (rendered inside child component)

```
constructor(private confirmationService: ConfirmationDialogService) { }
    ngAfterViewChecked(){
        this.checkForDirtyForm();
    }

    checkForDirtyForm(){
        for(var i = 0; i < this.ContactFormArr.length; i++){
            if(this.ContactFormArr.at(i).dirty){
                this.confirmationService.componentHasDirtyForm = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Basically, in grandchild component I am trying to set componentHasDirtyForm prop of ConfirmationDialogService. It is read correctly in parent if I set it from child but not grandchild.

I have included the service as a provider in app.module.ts

Comment: Are all components in same module?  See if `@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})` helps.

Comment: @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root', }) should help

Comment: I find your solution difficult. If you want and need to manage a form between nested components, I would suggest you to implement [ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor). It's impressive at the beginning, but it will probably help and solve your "dirty" issues :)

Comment: I have added that and it doesn't help

Comment: Use an observable for that.

Comment: @Emilien its not a form between several different components. All the child components have their own form. I want the parent to know if any single child component has a dirty form.

Comment: @ColbyBoren Oh okay ! I haven't understood (:

Comment: @ritaj so you are saying that making the property in the service an observable will solve the issue?

Comment: @ColbyBoren Yes, if you subscribe to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the issue. 
The Grandchildren/Children components were setting the service's value correctly. The issue was the Parent/Child component's `ngAfterViewChecked()` hook was running after the hooks in the Grandchildren/Children.

This was causing the service's value to basically always reflect the Parent components status (The component higher up in the chain). I got around the issue by setting the dirty check in the parent component to conditionally modify the service depending on its current value.

For example

```
isDirty(): boolean {
    if(!this.confirmService.componentHasDirtyForm)
        this.confirmService.componentHasDirtyForm = formStatus;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your service is declared like

```
@Injectable(
{
  provide:root
})
```

(is Wand Maker comment) the service is common to all the application

Else, you declare de service as providers:[] in the main module (and the service is common to all the aplication) or declare as providers:[] in a module witch has all the components.

If you declare the service as provider of each component or inject using Injector, the service is different fo each component

Comment: I have rewritten it to follow your answer and am still having the same problem. The grandchild component's changes to the service don't seem to be registering in the parent component.

Comment: if you convert your function isDirty() in a getter `get isDirty(){...}` you must see in `{{isDirty}}` the value unless you has changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap componentHasDirtyForm inside your service as an observable and then link that to all your components (parent, child, grandchild). That way all three (or more) all share the same value all the time.

```
// service
private readonly _componentHasDirtyForm = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});
public readonly $componentHasDirtyForm = this._data.asObservable();

// component
public componentHasDirtyForm: Observable<any>;

ngAfterViewChecked() {
   this.componentHasDirtyForm = confirmationService.$componentHasDirtyForm;
}    

// template
<div>{{ componentHasDirtyForm | async }}</div>
```

Comment: What would be the benefit of using an observable over a regular boolean in this situation?

Comment: So that you always have the most up to date value. Instead of setting your value once in the ngAfterViewChecked you're subscribing to any changes to that observable. This way the order in which the components load/update doesn't matter. Using this pattern you don't have to worry about dealing with the problem you're facing.